# How do I generate an encrypted password string, as it is in /etc/shadow?

Tags: cryptography, sha512, passwd, cryptographic-hash-function

I'm trying to mimic the creation of password strings as they appear in /etc/shadow.

This is what I've got so far, but the encrypted passwords don't match, when I use the same password and the same salt.

5000 rounds is standard for crypt, so I used that as well, but I don't see where exacly I made a mistake:

I'm doing this in Perl, this is the relevant porion:

```
($pass, $salt) = @ARGV;

unless(defined($salt)) {
    $salt = MIME::Base64::encode(random_bytes(12), '');
}

for $i (1 .. 4999) {
    $pass = Digest::SHA::sha512($salt, $pass);
}

say "";

print '$6$', $salt, '$', Digest::SHA::sha512_base64($salt, $pass), "\$\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crypt algorithm involves *a lot* more than just re-hashing 5,000 times:

- [Unix crypt using SHA-256 and SHA-512](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt)

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting something like this. Thanks, I'll read through it and accept if it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: The document say: "2.  the password string is added to digest A. 3.  the salt string is added to digest A." Does that mean, that first I append the salt to the password string? If so, that would be the other way round for MD5, which prefixes passwords with salt.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting there, I also cross checked with http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/branches/eglibc-2_9/libc/crypt/sha512-crypt.c?rev=7350&view=markup, interestingly, there are some documentation errors... I don't quite get the last part, where he makes the Base64, is that reversed byte order?

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -e 'print crypt("qwerty", "\$6\$somesalt\$")'
```